# pictures vanishes from my phone after sometimes

Tags: windows-10-mobile, photos

when I capture or download any picture, it shows in the gallery for a while but after I reopen the gallery then doesn't show not even after connecting to my laptop. I don't know where it goes but it gets totally vanished from my phone